# Limit point versus limit and implications for convergence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I understand that similar questions to this have been asked [here (1)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65094/proof-of-limit-and-limit-point) and [here (2)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21317/difference-between-limit-point-and-limit) but I believe my question is different because with regards to (1) I am not asking about the set $X$ that contains the points of my sequence and with regard to (2) because I have the distinct definitions of *limit* and *limit point* in mind. That said:

**My Question**: My textbook, Fundamental Ideas of Analysis by Michael Reed, defines a limit point as:

> **Definition**: Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence of real numbers. A number $d$ is called a **limit point** if, given $\epsilon > 0$ and an integer $N$, there exists $\color{red}{\mathrm{ an }} \ n \ge N$ so that $|a_n - d| \le \epsilon$.

The definition of a *limit* is as follows:

> **Definition**: We say that a sequence $(a_n)$ converges to a **limit** $a$ if, for every $\epsilon \ge 0$, there is an integer $N(\epsilon)$ so that $|a_n - a| \le \epsilon \color{red}{\text{  for all  }} n \ge N$.

From these definitions, and given this question:

> If a sequence converges it has exactly one limit point. Is the converse true? If not, provide a counterexample

Can I conclude that the converse is indeed true simply by appealing to the definitions, or do I need a tighter proof. And if I do, I'm a little stuck on how to refine this proof.

Comment: Could an unbounded sequence have exactly one limit point?

Comment: Does a sequence of this form "count"?: $(a_n) = 1$ for $n = 2k, k \in \mathbb N$, $(a_n) = n$ for $n = 2k - 1, k \in \mathbb N$?

Comment: Yes, its only limit point is $1$ but it does not converge.

Comment: So that sequence I have constructed works as a counterexample then. Thanks @DavidMitra

Comment: Hi, How do you prove that if a sequence converges it has a unique limit point?

Comment: I believe you have to prove $(1)$ that a sequence cannot converge with 0 limit points and $(2)$ that a sequence with $\geq 2$ limit points will not converge either.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The sequence $2,1/2,3,1/3,4,1/4 \cdots, n,1/n \cdots$ has the only limit point $0$, but not converges.

Answer (score 4):

You could also pick the sequence

$ (1 + (-1)^n).n $

which doesn't converge but has 0 as limit point.

Comment: To be explicit: it is the sequence $0,4,0,8,0,12,0,\dots$